# Error en eliminacion de llave foranea - wrong in drop foreign key postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the following query:

```
alter table hlt_citas drop constraint Ref_hlt_citas_to_hlt_atencion;
```

When I query the structure of the table, the part of the foreign key is the following:

```
"Ref_hlt_citas_to_hlt_atencion" FOREIGN KEY (cod_atencion)
REFERENCES hlt_atencion(cod_atencion) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

But when I run the query it tells me that it does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When identifiers like column or constraint names are given in double quotes, the identifiers become case-sensitive. You should then also use double-quotes in queries to maintain the case-sensitivity:

```
alter table hlt_citas drop constraint "Ref_hlt_citas_to_hlt_atencion";
```